# How to create duration in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation

Today i'm asking myself how to create a duration parameter like GreenSock does with its functions.

To be clear, how to create an animating function that takes a duration in pure vanilla JavaScript ?

Are they doing it by adding a transition-duration with JavaScript ? :)
I would like a solution in plain JS.

I have some ideas, maybe width :

```
new Date()
```

Or some :

```
setInterval()
```

For example how to handle the duration here ?

HTML :

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const box =   document.querySelector('.box');
function move(duration){
  box.style.transform =  "translateX(50px)";
}
move(2000)
```

Thank's if someone is passing by to give me a hand ! :)

Comment: Use the WebAPI to set `transition-property: transform` and `transition-duration: 2000ms`?

Comment: Well, i'm looking for a solution without CSS transition-duration if possible, I already know that.
Do Greensock use CSS transition-duration under the hood ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use an animation library. But, I made an example by using "translate3d". Translate3d runs on the GPU and not in the CPU, because of this is more performant. I put a pure CSS example as well.

```js
const box =   document.querySelector('.box');
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue');

function move(elem, duration){
  let posx = elem.getBoundingClientRect().x
  let counter = duration
  
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
     if (counter <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer)
     }
     
     posx += 2
     elem.style.transform = `translate3d(${posx}px,0,0)`
     counter -= 10
  }, 10)
}

move(box, 2000)

setTimeout(() => blue.classList.add('act'), 1000)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
}

.blue {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.act {
  transform: translate3d(100px,0,0)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<br>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution actually, thank you for that !

Comment: You should use `requestAnimationFrame` and not `setInterval` when animating elements.

Comment: You are correctly @BenAston!! I should have used `requestAnimatioFrame` instead. Much more performant!! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')

function move(duration){
  box.style['transition-property'] = 'transform'
  box.style['transition-duration'] = `${duration}ms`
  setTimeout(() => box.style.transform =  "translate3d(200px,0,0)")
}

move(2000)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

If you don't want to leverage CSS for the transition control then you will have to control it manually using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and your own easing function:

```js
const EASE_IN_OUT = (t) => 
  t < 0.5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1

const ease = (f, easing = EASE_IN_OUT) => (...args) => easing(f(...args))

const limit = (f, limit = 1) => (...args) => 
  { const result = f(...args); return result > limit ? limit : result }

const elapsedFraction = ({ start, duration }) => 
  (performance.now() - start) / duration

const asInteger = (f) => (...args) => f(...args).toFixed(0)

const calcX = asInteger(({ start, duration, distance }) => 
  ease(limit(elapsedFraction))({ start, duration }) * distance)

function move({ el, duration, distance }) {
  const start = performance.now()
  const startX = el.getBoundingClientRect().x

  const tick = () => {
    if (el.getBoundingClientRect().x - startX === distance) return
    el.style.transform = `translate3d(${calcX({ start, duration, distance })}px,0,0)`
    requestAnimationFrame(tick)
  }

  tick()
}

const el = document.querySelector(".box")
move({ el, duration: 1000, distance: 200 })
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: That is nice, but is there a solution without CSS transition-duration ? 
Is GSAP using CSS transition under the hood ?

Comment: This is really nice, a bit hard to grasp though, this is why I validated the other one.
But your solution is really good too, plus it adds an easing which is great.

Answer (score 0):

I think this function do what you want:

```js
Element.prototype.move = function(duration, distance) {
  this.style.transition = duration + 's';
  this.style.transform =  'translateX(' + distance + 'px)';;
};
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="this.move(2, 400);">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: Animating margin is a bad idea in term of performances, and i'm looking for a way without CSS transition-duration. Thanks for this though ! :)